# ASP problem with displaying content across 2 col setup in Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues with a footer showing up across 2-column setup in Chrome and Mozilla. works ok in IE8.

I am writing asp with css includes to display the footer. css code for footer is this:

```
    #siteInfo{
      clear: both;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #cccccc;
      border-width: 1px;
      font-size: 75%;
      color: #000000;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

I have tried the shorthand of `border:1px solid #cccccc;` as well with no effect.
while footer itsself is this:

```
<!-- PAGE FOOTER -->
 <!-- DO NOT EDIT CODE BELOW! --> 

<div id="siteInfo"> 
  Materials provided are for <strong>Educational Use Only</strong>. Published articles are the Copyright of their respective publishers. All other material is Copyright &copy;2011 XXX. You're welcome to use any of my material for eductional or non-commercial use, provided it is in its original form, and I am recognized as its author. Please post links rather than posting copies of the files, so that your users get any updates which I post here. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That it works in IE is of no consequence when it doesn't work in the modern browsers. Never use IE as a reference for things working. Since ASP frequently generates non-standard markup, it's best to supply a link.

Answer (score 0):

As of my experience the best way to fix a footer is using a master page which is in a tabular format using panels.

3 panels vertically place one below the other (a division might do as well)
{note div is faster than span} when browser tries to load but some attributes of `div` like align is not supported across various browsers like IE7, Safari.

So I advise you to use framesets like this:

```
<frameset rows="10%,80%,10%">

  <frame src="frame_a.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_b.htm" />
  <frame src="frame_c.htm" />

</frameset>
```

Inside `frame_c.htm` set the footer.

Comment: That seems a bit of a step backwards using framesets, especially when a div styled correctly is way more efficient (div 'may be slower' than using span, but 3 extra calls to a server is by far slower)